# Como resolver loop infinito de requisição React.js?

Tags: javascript, react

Na rota *GET* que carrego imagem do backend no `useState` que esta em um componente do react fica fazendo requisição infinita para o meu backend

código do componente:

```js
    
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import{FiTrash2} from 'react-icons/fi'
import {Link} from  'react-router-dom'
 
import api from '../../../services/api';
import './stylesimp.css' 

function MPetImagem(props){
    async function deleteImg(imagem){
        api.delete('imagem',{
            headers:{
                name:imagem.name,
                id:imagem.id
            }
        });
        setImagem(imagens.filter(incident=> incident.id !== imagem.id))

    }
    const [imagens,setImagem] = useState([]);

    const {pet} = props;
   
    useEffect(()=>{
        api.get('imagem',{
            headers:{
                authorization:pet.id,
            }
        }).then(response => setImagem(response.data))
    })

    return(
        <ul>
            {imagens.slice(0,3).map(imagem =>(
                <li key={imagem.id}>
                    <Link onClick={()=>deleteImg(imagem)}><FiTrash2></FiTrash2></Link>
                    <img src={imagem.url} alt="imagem pet"></img>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
           
        
    )
}
export default MPetImagem;
```

[image: Screenshot do código do componente 1]
[image: Screenshot do código do componente 2]
<sup>Screenshots do código do componente. *Click na imagem para visualizar em seu tamanho original*</sup>

Onde o componente é chamado

```js
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {Link,useHistory} from  'react-router-dom'
import{FiEdit,FiImage, FiTrash2} from 'react-icons/fi'
import api from '../../services/api'


import Logo from '../../assests/images.png'

import ImgPet from '../componente/imgmeuspets'

import cat from '../../assests/rascuepetlogo.png'



import './stylesmp.css'

export default function PetsPerdidos(){
    
    const [pets,setPets]= useState([]);
    const history = useHistory();

    const dono_id = localStorage.getItem('dono_id');
  
useEffect(()=>{
        api.get('meuspets',{
            headers:{
                authorization:dono_id,
            }

        }).then(response=>{setPets(response.data)})
        localStorage.removeItem('pet_id');
    },[dono_id]);

    function Position(id,local){
        localStorage.setItem('pet_id',id);

        history.push(`/${local}`)

        
    }
    
    async function DeletePet(id){
        try{ 
         await api.delete(`pets/${id}`,{
             headers:{
                 authorization:dono_id
             }
         });
         setPets(pets.filter(pet=> pet.id!== id))

       

       
    }catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }

    }
  

 

    
    return (
    <div className="meuspets-container">

        
         <header>
             
             <img src={cat} alt="logo"></img>
             <Link class="button" to="/petsperdidos">Home</Link> 
             <Link class="button" to="/newpet">Cadastrar Pet</Link>
               
                
               

                
        </header>
       
        <h1>Meus Pets</h1>
        <ul>
            {pets.map(pet=>(
            <li  key={pet.id}>
                <h3>{pet.name}</h3>
            
            <Link className="editar" onClick={()=>Position(pet.id,'editar')}><FiEdit/> Editar pet</Link>
            <Link className="editar" onClick={()=>Position(pet.id,'adicionar-imagem')}><FiImage/> Adicionar imagem</Link>
            <button className="button-delete" onClick={()=>DeletePet(pet.id)}><FiTrash2></FiTrash2></button>
            
            <header>
            
            
            
            
            </header>
            <section>
                <ImgPet pet={pet}></ImgPet>
                
            
            </section>
            
            <strong>Recompensa:</strong>
            <p>{Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR',{style:'currency',currency:'BRL'}).format(pet.value)}</p>
            
 
            <strong>Descrição:</strong>
            <p>{pet.description}</p>
           
            
           
           <form>

               
                

                      
        </form>
            
             <div className="link">
             <Link className="button"  onClick={()=>Position(pet.id,'position')}>Ver Localizações</Link>
             </div>
           
            

        </li>
        ))}
        
        </ul>
      
    </div>
       
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu código o [useEffect](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) precisa saber o que fazer, o código não sabe qual é o momento da sua parada ou o momento que o mesmo pode ser executado.

Como o código deve ser executado uma única vez ao criar o componente, precisa configurar um `array` sem nenhum posição estipulada, exemplo:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    api.get('imagem',{
        headers:{
            authorization:pet.id,
        }
    }).then(response => setImagem(response.data))
},[]) // <--------------
```

dessa forma será executado a única vez no momento da criação do componente.

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Usando Effect Hook (Hook de Efeito)](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)